# Mode_switch + Shift not the same as Shift + Mode_Switch?

Tags: xmodmap

I've this in my `~/.Xmodmap`:

```
keycode  47 = Mode_switch NoSymbol Mode_switch
keycode  25 = w W backslash bar
```

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Mode_switch</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> produces bar, which is what's intended.
However <kbd>Mode_switch</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> produces W.
Why is this?

As I was writing this question, I've made this replacement:

```
keycode  47 = Mode_switch Mode_switch Mode_switch
```

and now the problem disappeared. However I've seen `Mode_switch NoSymbol Mode_switch` used
many times. Can someone explain why the change fixes the problem? Any pitfalls to this method?